# Merge different dataset

Tags: r, join, merge, union

I have a question, I need to merge two different dataset in one but they have a different class. How I can I do? rbind doesn't work, ideas?

```
nycounties <- rgdal::readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_provinces.geojson")

city <- c("Novara", "Milano","Torino","Bari")
dimension <- c("150000", "5000000","30000","460000")
df <- cbind(city, dimension)
 
total <- rbind(nycounties,df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
nycounties@data = data.frame(nycounties@data,
                             df[match(nycounties@data[, "prov_name"],
                                      df[, "city"]),])
```

**Output**

```
nycounties@data[!is.na(nycounties@data$dimension),]

   prov_name prov_istat_code_num prov_acr  reg_name reg_istat_code reg_istat_code_num prov_istat_code   city dimension
0     Torino                   1       TO  Piemonte             01                  1             001 Torino     30000
2     Novara                   3       NO  Piemonte             01                  1             003 Novara    150000
12    Milano                  15       MI Lombardia             03                  3             015 Milano   5000000
81      Bari                  72       BA    Puglia             16                 16             072   Bari    460000
```

Comment: Yes, but in my original file it doesn't work, the match is always null. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: In my original dataset df isn't a chr

Comment: @Inuraghe I used the data that you provided. So, you'll have to provide a more specific example with what the error is, and what you want the expected output to be, and data that would replicate the error. Other than that, I would just be guessing.